# python: how to check if a line is an empty line

Tags: python

Trying to figure out how to write an if cycle to check if a line is empty.

The file has many strings, and one of these is a blank line to separate from the other statements (not a `""`; is a carriage return followed by another carriage return I think)

```
new statement
asdasdasd
asdasdasdasd

new statement
asdasdasdasd
asdasdasdasd
```

Since I am using the file input module, is there a way to check if a line is empty?

Using this code it seems to work, thanks everyone!

```
for line in x:

    if line == '\n':
        print "found an end of line"

x.close()
```

Answer (score 163, accepted):

If you want to ignore lines with only whitespace:

```
if line.strip():
    ... do something
```

The empty string is a False value.

Or if you really want only empty lines:

```
if line in ['\n', '\r\n']:
    ... do  something
```

Comment: the second one does what I had in mind, Thanks!

if line in ['\n']:

Comment: If you are only using `if line in ['\n']`, you should replace that with `if line == '\n'`.

Comment: I would like to point out that the accepted answer, has an error: if line.strip(): ... #do something ignores lines with whitespace i.e. space, tab and empty line. That's why only the second one worked for the original poster: the 'not' has to be removed.

Comment: if not line.strip(): ... do something . Shouldn't it continue instead ? because if not line.strip() actually means that line is empty so nothing can be stripped from it, hence ignore or continue.     The first part not line.strip() catches all empty lines

Comment: Would it be cleaner to use `os.linesep` instead of `['\n', '\r\n']`?

Comment: @retracile , if line in ['\n', '\r\n'], this doesn't check for empty line.

Comment: @retracile I've been some time trying to understand why your answer was right, and seeing last comments I see that there is a mistake. Please, would you change the first sentence you've written by this?: "If you want to proceed with lines with only whitespace:". This sentence is the right for the followed code.

Comment: @KandanSiva, what does it check then? Do you understand what this code means?

Answer (score 37):

I use the following code to test the empty line with or without white spaces.

```
if len(line.strip()) == 0 :
    # do something with empty line
```

Comment: # do something with empty line -- > what if i wanted to remove the line?

Answer (score 12):

```
line.strip() == ''
```

Or, if you don't want to "eat up" lines consisting of spaces:

```
line in ('\n', '\r\n')
```

Comment: In the second sample you'd probably also like to check for `\r\n` to account for Windows-style line endings (CRLF)

Comment: forgot to mention that this is running on a Unix machine, so it uses the newline without the \r. Tried it thou but it didn't work, what is working for me: if line in ['\n']: (no clue why the line =="\n" won't work)

Comment: @user1006198: if you're only checking for `\n`, then `line == '\n'` is better.  You should probably try it again and figure out what your problem was.

Comment: @user1006198: (1) Reading a Windows-created text file on Unix will give you `\r\n` if you are not using `mode='rU'` (2) Get a clue: `print repr(line)` and if that doesn't provide a clue, tell us exactly what "doesn't work" means to you.

Comment: The only explanation that i have is that probably the file input does something to each line, because when i do the comparison of the line with the == i don't hit the statement (printing a string to see if i hit the blank line, and with the == it never print the debug line, while it does it when i use the "if line in").

Comment: @user1006198: What you say is very implausible. Show your code.

Comment: Added the code that i use on the main post; tried to paste formatted code in the comment but was just making a mess

Comment: @user1006198: sorry, your code in the "main post" doesn't make much sense. Just stick this one line of code somewhere in your loop: `print line == '\n', line in ['\n'], repr(line)` ... if you get any output that starts with `False True`, show us that output AND your print statement -- NOTE: copy/paste (i.e. NOT typed from memory)

Comment: Sorry John, just messed up the code; the print line == '\n' works just fine; human error :) Using that instead of the line in [\n']. For some reason python gets bonk when you modify a file and run it; closed the shell window and opened it again and it started to work.

Answer (score 2):

You should open text files using `rU` so newlines are properly transformed, see http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open. This way there's no need to check for `\r\n`.

Comment: tried the open but i find file input more suitable for my case

Comment: It should also be noted that the `U` argument is not supported in python3.

Answer (score 2):

I think is more robust to use regular expressions:

```
import re

for i, line in enumerate(content):
    print line if not (re.match('\r?\n', line)) else pass
```

This would match in Windows/unix. In addition if you are not sure about lines containing only space char you could use  `'\s*\r?\n'` as expression