# ValueError : need more than one value to unpack

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, collections, deque

I'm coding a quiz and after the student completes the quiz, when saving the scores, I'm trying to ensure that a student's last three scores are saved to their names. If they haven't completed a quiz before, a new line is written for them within the the text file.

```
filename = (str(class_number) + 'txt')
with open(filename, 'a') as f:
    f.write(str(name) + " : " + str(score) + '\n')

with open(filename) as f:
    f.seek(0)
    scores = f.readline()
    from collections import deque
    for line in scores:
        name, score = line.rstrip('\n').split(',')
        score= int(score)
        if name not in filename:
            filename[name] = deque(maxlen=3)
        temp_q = filename[name]
        temp_q.append(str(score))
        filename[name] = temp_q

    filehandle = open (filename, 'w')
    for key,values in filename.iteritems():
        filehandle.write(name + ',')
        filehandle.write (','.join(list(values)) + '\n')
    filehandle.close()
```

And this is the error:

```
name, score = line.rstrip('\n').split(',')
Value error need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at what `line` is?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19749077/valueerror-need-more-than-1-value-to-unpack)

Answer (score 1):

This error message indicates, that there's no `,` character in the file you are trying to read from.

Answer (score 0):

Your `line` does not have a comma in it. Therefore trying to unpack it to two variables fail after splitting (since the split delimiter does not exist in the line). Print your lines to debug this and see what is actually contained in your lines.

Comment: Do I do this by simply just removing the comma

Comment: No. You are trying to unpack 2 values but you only get 1 back. To get 2 values you need to really have some kind of delimiter in your line. If you just want the line itself then use 1 variable and remove the split altogether.

Comment: Sorry to bother you but I don't know what delimiter means

Comment: Delimiter is the comma (,) you use in the `split`.