# python "need more than 1 value to unpack"

Tags: python, python-2.7

Trying to run a script from "Learn Python the hard way" and getting this error, tried several things but I'm kinda stuck. Seen similar errors with people using argv and not enough arguments when running the script

Error points to Line 70:

```
question, answer = convert(snippet, phrase)
```

full code:

```
import random
from urllib import urlopen
import sys

WORD_URL = "http://learncodethehardway.org/words.txt"
WORDS = []

PHRASES = {
        "class %%%(%%%):":
            "Make a class named %%% that is-a %%%",
        "class %%%(object):\n\tdef __init__(self, ***)" :
            "class %%% has-a __init__ that takes self and *** parameters.",
        "class %%%(object):\n\tdef ***(self, @@@)" :
            "class %%% has-a function named *** that takes self and @@@ parameters.",
        "*** = %%%()":
            "Set *** to an instance of class %%%",
        "***.***(@@@)":
            "From *** get the *** function, nd call it with parameters self, @@@",
        "***.*** = '***'":
            "From *** get the *** attribute and set it to '***'."
            }
#do they want to drill phrases first

PHRASE_FIRST = False
if len(sys.argv) == 2 and sys.argv[1] == "English":
    PHRASE_FIRST = True

#load up the words from the website
for word in urlopen(WORD_URL).readlines():
    WORDS.append(word.strip())


def convert(snippet, phrase):
    class_names = [w.capitalize() for w in
    random.sample(WORDS, snippet.count("%%%"))]
    other_names = random.sample(WORDS, snippet.count("***"))
    results = []
    param_names = []

    for i in range(0, snippet.count("@@@")):
        param_count = random.randint(1, 3)
        param_names.append(", ".join(random.sample(WORDS, param_count)))

    for sentence in snippet, phrase:
        result = sentence[:]

#fake class names
    for word in class_names:
        result = result.replace("%%%", word, 1)

    #fake other names

    for word in other_names:
        result = result.replace("***", word, 1)

    for word in param_names:
        result = result.replace("@@@", word, 1)

    results.append(result)
    return results

#keep going until they hit CTRL-D
try:
        while True:
            snippets = PHRASES.keys()
            random.shuffle(snippets)

            for snippet in snippets:
                phrase = PHRASES[snippet]
                question, answer = convert(snippet, phrase)
                if PHRASE_FIRST:
                    question, answer = answer, question
                print question

            raw_input("> ")
            print "ANSWER: %s\n\n" % answer
except EOFError:
    print "\nBye"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19749077/valueerror-need-more-than-1-value-to-unpack)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Problem**

In your code, convert() returns a list, which is **one** object, or value. By doing `question, answer = convert(snippet, phrase)`, you are expecting two values to be returned, and then inserted into `question` and `answer`.

**Solution**

You should a change

```
question, answer = convert(snippet, phrase)
```

to

```
results = convert(snippet, phrase)
```

You can then get question and answer from results(assuming they are at indices 0 and 1) by doing

```
question = results[0]
answer = results[1]
```

Comment: Thank you, really annoying when you are learning from something which isn't correct. The code posted above is directly from the book. I will try to tweak it like you said

Comment: Ok, comment if you have any troubles.

Comment: How does this solve OP's problem? As you noted the list only has one element (which from your code it looks like this is likely due to poor indentation). So, unpacking into two variables will fail just like indexing it as if there are two elements will fail... This is trading one problem for another.

Comment: The problem was with the return value of the function. The list, on the other hand, also has a problem.  I just noted that you can later access the values in the list **assuming they are at indices 0 and 1**. I am not entirely sure what `question` and `answer` are supposed to represent.

Answer (score 2):

The above comments are correct for the issue you are experiencing however the code example posted is not showing correct indentation. The `for sentence in snippet, phrase` loop in the class is not appending the extra value that will then result in a correct `question, answer = convert(snippet, phrase)`.
Change the code to the below and it should run fine(tested it here):

```
for sentence in snippet, phrase:
    result = sentence[:]

    #fake class names
    for word in class_names:
        result = result.replace("%%%", word, 1)

    #fake other names
    for word in other_names:
        result = result.replace("***", word, 1)

    for word in param_names:
        result = result.replace("@@@", word, 1)

    results.append(result)
return results
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to unpack two values from `results` which is returned by your function `convert(*args)`.

However, in your function `convert` you are returning a list with a single item `result` which is appended to `results`. So, you only have one value not two to unpack

For the sake of completeness....

Let's say your function `convert` *returned more than two values* in this list and you tried to unpack them. You'd also get an error, but this time you'd have too many values to unpack. In this case you do something along the lines of this:

```
some_var, *other = convert(snippet, phrase)
```