# Why am I receiving a ValueError?

Tags: python

I have two files which look exactly the same:
file1

```
1 in seattle today the secretary of education richard riley delivered his address 
1 one of the things he focused on as the president had done
1 abc's michele norris has been investigating this
2 we're going to take a closer look tonight at the difficulty of getting meaningful
```

file2

```
1 in seattl today the secretari of educ richard riley deliv hi address
1 one of the thing he focus on a the presid had done
1 abc michel norri ha been investig thi 
2 we'r go to take a closer look tonight at the difficulti of get meaning
```

When I run this code:

```
result=defaultdict(list)
with open("onthis.txt","r") as filer:
    for line in filer:
        label, sentence= line.strip().split(' ', 1)
        result[label].append(sentence)
```

It works perfectly for file1 but gives me a value error for file2:

```
label, sentence= line.strip().split(' ', 1)
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

I don't seem to catch the reason when they are both in the same format. 
So, I just removed the empty lines by this terminal command:

```
sed '/^$/d' onthis.txt > trial
```

But the same error appears.

Comment: Do you have an empty / white-space-only line at the end of your second file?

Comment: in general: `import pdb; pdb.pm()` will put you into the exception, and you can dump out `line` and see exactly what it's failing on.

Comment: I tried adding a if no line: continue, but it gave the same error again. There might be an empty line

Comment: Are you sure? I could reproduce your error with an added empty line. However with an `if line.strip():` that was easy to fix. Inspiration from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7896585/1063730 :)

Comment: @yoshi I still get the same Value Error if I try ignoring the empty line. Any other way to fix that?

Comment: You could update your question showing us how you try to ignore the empty line. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can't be exactly the same. My guess is that there is an empty / white-space-only line somewhere in your second file, most likely right at the end.

The error is telling you that when it is performing the split, there are no spaces to split on so only one value is being returned, rather than a value for both `label` and `sentence`.

Comment: I just removed all the white spaces via command line. But it is still producing the same error. Could there be any other reason for that?

Comment: No I don't think there could be any other reason. Try adding a `print(line)` right before you do the split. This will show you the lines that work, and more importantly, the last line it got to before the error occurrs

Comment: So I discovered on printing the lines that some lines have the labels but no sentences (empty space for sentences). A number of such lines.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your edit I suspect you might still have "empty" lines in your text file. Well I probably better should say: lines filled with nothing but white spaces.

I've extended your example file:

```
1 in seattl today the secretari of educ richard riley deliv hi address
1 one of the thing he focus on a the presid had done
1 abc michel norri ha been investig thi 
2 we'r go to take a closer look tonight at the difficulti of get meaning
 3   foo

4 bar


5 qun
```

It's probably not clear but the line between `3 foo` and `4 bar` is filled by a couple of white spaces while the lines between `4 bar` `5 qun` are "just" new lines (`\n`).

Notice the output of `sed '/^$/d'`

```
1 in seattl today the secretari of educ richard riley deliv hi address
1 one of the thing he focus on a the presid had done
1 abc michel norri ha been investig thi 
2 we'r go to take a closer look tonight at the difficulti of get meaning
 3   foo

4 bar
5 qun
```

The empty lines are truly removed - no doubt. But the pseudo-empty white space lines is still there. Running your python script will throw an error when reaching this line:

```
2 we'r go to take a closer look tonight at the difficulti of get meaning

 3   foo    

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python.py", line 9, in <module>
    label, sentence= line.strip().split(' ', 1)
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

So my suggestion would be to extend your script by one line, making it skip empty lines in your input file.

```
for line in filer:
    if not line.strip(): continue
```

Doing so has the positive side effect you don't have to prepare your input files with some `sed`-magic before.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the above that you have provided (with a tweak). This seems to give the expected result.

```
result = {}

with open("test.txt", "r") as filer:
    for line in filer:
        label, sentence = line.strip().split(' ', 1)
        try:
            result[label].append(sentence)
        except KeyError:
            result[label] = [sentence]
```

Output:

```
{'2': ["we'r go to take a closer look tonight at the difficulti of get meaning"], '1': ['in seattl today the secretari of educ richard riley deliv hi address', 'one of the thing he focus on a the presid had done', 'abc michel norri ha been investig thi']}
```

So this must mean that we there is something missing from what you have provided. I think that if the above doesn't give you what you need then more info is required

Comment: I get the same error again. :( I am not sure how to put the content up here because it is a huge file. Maybe on the discussion chat?

Comment: I think you've misunderstood. The error is when trying to assign `label` and `sentence` after the `split` has been performed, not when appending.

Comment: I got that was the error, the change was for a test I ran. My point is that with the data available there is no error. why dont you try adding a try block for us around the line that is throwing the error, catch the ValueError and print the "line" then you can see that line and add it here.