# Index Error - For Line in File: line.split into [1] and [2]

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, authentication

might be a silly question but maybe still someone can help me out. So inside my code i'm trying to use a text file to grap some log in data and repeat it. The code which is not working is the following.

```
Accs.txt file looks like:
User1:Passwort1
User2:Passwort2
User3:Passwort3

code.py looks like:
file = open('Accs.txt', 'r')
for acc in file:
    Mail=acc.split(':')[0]
    Passwort=acc.split(':')[1]
    print (Mail)
    print (Passwort)
```

after the text file graps the second acc on the list i get an index error. I guess there is some logical thing behind how it works which i dont get. Anybody could help me out?

Comment: hmm i ran same code and it worked fine, are there any extra blank lines in your text file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran the same code and it worked fine. 
If there are any extra blank lines in your text file, that index out of range exception can be thrown.

here is a workaround to handle blank lines (source: [python: how to check if a line is an empty line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896495/python-how-to-check-if-a-line-is-an-empty-line))

```
for acc in file:
    if acc.strip():
        lineSplit = acc.split(':')
        Mail=lineSplit[0]
        Passwort=lineSplit[1]
        print (Mail)
        print (Passwort)
```

Also , it is more efficient to use the split() method one time and store into a variable to access later by index later (also in code above)

Comment: Problem weren't any free spaces. What made it work was the if line. What makes it diffrent if i add an if? like why does it work now but not before

Comment: Well but now he takes those lines before the last line 2 times

Comment: my guess is you're not seeing the weird/formatting and/or spacing in the text editor you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You should go

```
for line in file.read():
      line = line.split(":")
      mail=line[0]
      pass=line[1]
```

Read the file must go file.read()

Sorry for the layout I'm using my phone :)