# Why are blank lines being added in CSV file when running python script multiple times?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am currently trying to build a python 3 script that will take a csv file, read it, and then copy the rows and add them to the end of a file. This script is going to run daily as the data dump from the application will run daily.

I have the code "working" to get the file and copy it and it does work on each run, but it is adding several blank lines to the end of the file each time. so for instance the first time i run it, it is on lines 1-101, but the next time it might be lines 9000-9101.

```
newest = r'C:\Users\me\downloads\Test2.csv'
with open(r'C:\Users\me\downloads\out.csv', 'a', newline='') as repository:
    fileWriter = csv.writer(repository, delimiter=',')
    with open(newest, 'r', newline='') as newData:
        fileReader = csv.reader(newData, delimiter=',')
        next(fileReader)
        for row in fileReader:
            fileWriter.writerow(row)


print("Copy Complete")
```

I would like for it to not have the blank lines between it. as it may cause issues with the app I am trying to use to view the data.

Comment: It sounds like you have empty lines at the end of `Test2.csv` file

Comment: Are the number of blank lines that get written to the file random?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the csv that you're using as the input contains blank lines. I'd add a check in your for row loop to make sure that you're only adding lines with data in them to your output file. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896495/python-how-to-check-if-a-line-is-an-empty-line) may be helpful to checking on if the lines in your input file are blank or not.

Comment: you know... sometimes you do something to try to shrink your data set so that it is easier to test, and you end up causing more issues than you would like lol. 

thanks for this.. i tried with another CSV and it worked fine.