# Is there a way for Python to detect whether a value is empty?

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to write a piece of code that will take certain values in a string and output them. The problem is the dataset I'm working with isn't perfect and there are many parts where the data is empty. I'm looking for a way to get python to ignore the blank values and just continue onwards

```
rfile = open("1.txt", "r", encoding= "utf8")
combos = rfile.readlines()
a=0
nfile = open("2.txt ", "w+")

numx = 0

for line in combos:
    x = combos[a]
    y=(x.split('Points = '))
    z= int(y[-1])
    numx += 1
    print (z)

print (numx)
rfile.close()
nfile.close()
exi = input("Press any key to close")
```

Example of the dataset would be like:

```
Person 1 | Points = 22 
Person 2 | Points =     <--- This is the problematic data 
Person 3 | Points = 15
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just to clarify, I want python to check whether z is empty, and if it is to just ignore it.

Comment: `if z:` should work.

Comment: You can just check if `y[-1]` is the empty string `""`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python: how to check if a line is an empty line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896495/python-how-to-check-if-a-line-is-an-empty-line)

Comment: `z= y[-1] != ''? int(y[-1]) : ''`

Comment: More generally, see this answer for what Python considers to be True or False: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491777/truth-value-of-a-string-in-python and [the official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html)

Comment: Look at the `y` in the problem line.  What is it?  string, list, Nine, etc?

Answer (score 1):

You can check if variable is empty string, or just None, thy something like:
`if not value: continue`

Answer (score 0):

After

```
    y = (x.split('Points = '))
```

If it is **guaranteed** that the lines with missing data only have a **single** space after the `=`, e.g. `'Person 2 | Points = '` so that `y[-1] == ''`, you can simply do the following to skip over this one and carry on (goes to the start of the next iteration of the `for` loop):

```
    if not y:
        continue
```

relying on the fact that an empty string counts as a false value.

If it might contain additional whitespace, then you will have to deal with this.  There are various options:

1. test the characters of the string one by one

```
    for c in y[-1]:   # looping over the characters in y[-1]
        if c != ' ':  # if a non-space character is found
            break     # then break from this inner "for" loop
    else:             # but if this loop completed without break
        continue      # then start next iteration of the outer "for" loop
```

2. use a regular expression parser (needs `import re` at the top)

```
    if re.match('\s*$', y[-1]):
        continue
```

3. just try to convert it to int anyway, and catch the exception if it fails:

```
    try:
        z = int(y[-1])
    except ValueError:
        continue
```

(All of these will still work if the string is indeed empty.)