# Use row and col to find a letter in a txt.file

Tags: python

I have created a txt.file containing different sentences, there is no connection between the placement of the letters, and would like to save that as a dictionary in Python and then use row and col to determine any specific letter in this file.

In the code I would like to get Python to ask two questions to determine a specific letter:

1. Ask which file to look in
2. Ask for two coordinates (row-and column number)

Here is what I got so far:

```
def save_rows(filename):           
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        answer = {}
        for line in f:
            line = line.split()
            if not line:  # empty line?
                continue
            answer[line[0]] = line[1:]

        
def main():
    filename = input("Input the file:")
    indexed_file = save_rows(filename)
    row = input("Input row-and column number:")
```

How to I proceed from this?

Comment: Making a `dict` out of the lines of the file is unnecessary complication, at least for this specific problem. Do you need that structure for other things you'll be doing elsewhere in your code?

Comment: Hi, no i do not need that structure for other things in this one but I do need to learn how to do it. However right now I am more interested in how I can find which letter is on the two coordinates.

Comment: You appear to be looping through your lines, but not stopping on the specified Row. The Col looks good, but keep in ,ind that the user could provide a Column greater than the highest one in the Row.

Comment: You are counting lines and columns, do you start counting from 1, like a human, or from 0, like a python?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try with [`linecache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/linecache.html):

```py
import linecache

def main():
    filename = input("Input the file: ")
    line_num, col_num = [int(x) for x in input("Input row-and column number: ").split()]
    line = linecache.getline(filename, line_num)
    linecache.clearcache()
    if not line.strip() and col_num > 0 and col_num < len(line):
        print(line[col_num-1])
    else:
        print(f'No letter in line {line_num} and col {col_num}')
```

- `linecache.getline()` opens the file and gets the desired line
- `linecache.clearcache()` is here in case you modify the line you read before (by, say, editing the file) and want to read (and cache) the modified line
- `not line.strip()` skips lines with whitespaces only (see [python: how to check if a line is an empty line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896495/python-how-to-check-if-a-line-is-an-empty-line/7896585) for details, including how to check for empty lines)
- `col_num-1` is needed assuming that the user uses `1` to specify the 1st column

If you want to save the lines that do not have only whitespaces in a `dict`, your `save_rows()` can be simplified as:

```py
def save_rows(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return {i:line for i, line in enumerate(f) if line.strip()}
```

This way you will have a `dict` with `keys` the line numbers and `values` the lines.

**EDIT (based on the ask in the comments):** For implementing some logic around the allowed input, you could try:

```py
import sys

while True:
    user_input = input("Input row-and column number: ")
    if user_input == 'exit':
        sys.exit()
    try:
        line_num, col_num = [int(x) for x in user_input.split()]
    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid input. Try again.')
    else:
        break

print(line_num, col_num)
```

The piece above waits until the user enters a valid input. In this case, this is exactly two numbers. If the user does not provide a valid input, a message is printed and the user is presented again with the prompt to provide two numbers. If the user enters less or more than two numbers a `ValueError` is raised. The same happens if the user does not enter numbers. Finally, it the user enters `exit` the program `exit`s. If you are not interested in giving the user multiple chances to enter a valid input (but only one), you can remove `while`.

Comment: Thank you! If I would like the program to quit when I write "exit" on the question "Input row-and col number" how would I do that? I tried if row and col == "exit" and then return but it did not work.

Comment: @idlatva I updated the answer. I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do it would be this:

```py
def get_char_at(filename, row, col):
    row = int(row)
    col = int(col)
    with open(filename) as f:
        lines = f.read().splitlines()
    if row >= len(lines):
        raise KeyError(f"File {filename} doesn't contain {row} lines")
    if col >= len(lines[row]):
        raise KeyError(f"Line {row} doesn't contain {col} characters")
    return lines[row][col]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename = input('Input file name: ')
    row = input('Input row: ')
    col = input('Input col: ')
    print(get_char_at(filename, row, col))
```

`f.read().splitlines()` is handy because it automatically removes the newline character at the end of each line. The main thing to note here is that lists (like `lines`) and strings (like each item in `lines`) are both indexable. `lines[row]` gets you the line you want, and `lines[row][col]` gets you the character in that line. Indices in Python start from zero, so as written, providing `0` and `0` will get you the first character in the file. You can subtract one as necessary to start by 1, if you'd prefer.

A note: this is a straightforward, but not necessarily the most foolproof way to do this. The main pitfall is that this reads the entire file into memory at once. That's usually fine for reasonably sized text files. If you need to handle very large files, it's more efficient to iterate through its lines rather than read them all at once. But then you won't be able to index right to the line you need. So the `get_char_at` might then look something like:

```py
def get_char_at(filename, row, col):
    row = int(row)
    col = int(col)
    with open(filename) as f:
        for index, line in enumerate(f):
            if index == row:
                if col >= len(line) - 1: # subtract to account for the newline
                    raise KeyError(f"Line {row} doesn't contain {col} characters")
                return line[col]
    raise KeyError(f"File {filename} doesn't contain {row} lines")
```

You loop through the lines of the file. `enumerate` provide an index for which line you're currently on. If you get the right line, return the character (assuming it has enough). On the other hand, if you get through the whole file without getting to the specified line, it clearly doesn't have that many lines.

Comment: Thank you! I tried this and it worked! And thank you for explaining the steps/code!

Comment: @idlatva Glad it worked! Please click the checkmark to accept the answer. (You can upvote it too, by clicking the up arrow.)