# Python reading starting from a certain word until that paragraph finishes

Tags: python, pdf, txt, pdfminer

I have a txt document which I have converted from a PDF using pdfminer. It has a summarization part in it, it usually is a page long in PDF. The problem is I can find the word Summarization with no problem using:

```
with open('output.txt',encoding="utf-8") as f:
if 'Summarization' in f.read():
    print("true")
```

But I am stuck at that. I don't have any ideas how can I read until the paragraph finishes.

The paragraph looks like this in PDF:
[PDF Summ Part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkHQK.png)

and it looks like this in txt: I've created from it:[TXT Summ Part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enncQ.png)

I'd be so happy if I can get any help. Thank you.

Comment: just read until the full empty line like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896495/python-how-to-check-if-a-line-is-an-empty-line/7896585)

Answer (score 0):

You can read until empty line:

```
with open('output.txt',encoding="utf-8") as f:
if 'Summarization' in f.read():
    print("true")
if f.read().strip() == '':
    print('It's new paragraph')
```